# How to do multi threading a function of class in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a class named `OlxScraper` which contains a method call `fetch_all_pages` that takes a URL as an input and fetches all the links and links inside links and then puts them into the database.

I have a list which contains 40,000 URL's. This is what I am doing right now:

```
list = [contain 40,000 urls]
olx = OlxScraper()
for li in list:
    olx.fetch_all_pages(li)
```

I have a high speed ethernet VPS and basically I want to fetch multiple links from a list at once. I would like to have 10 threads running at the same time, each thread should take 10 url's from the list and then run `olx.fetch_all_pages`.

How can I do that..?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. `Pool` will do nicely with your task, so your code might look like that:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

olx = OlxScraper()

parallel_workers = 10
p = Pool(parallel_workers)
p.map(olx.fetch_all_pages, list_of_urls)
```

Comment: Getting an error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Can you post complete trace? Doesn't look like `Pool` should make something like that happen

Comment: Check here: https://www.writeurl.com/text/da53bt8tqn8rcmbropcp/21dpnkj1wo19ir1stlpr

Comment: Didn't notice this line, that your code _"fetches all the links and links inside links"_. How does your class handle loops in links? I see no way `multiprocessing.Pool` could harm, my suggestion is to check the code behind `OlxScraper`